# Expansion of $e^z$ when $z$ is a complex number.

Tags: complex-numbers, taylor-expansion

Can we expand $e^z$ where $z$ is a complex number same as we expand $e^x$?

Comment: Yes, that is often times the definition of complex exponential (if by expand you mean use a series representation)

Comment: By expand I mean e^x = 1 + x + 1/2x^2 ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can. Moreover the expansion
$$
e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}
$$
is in fact the definition of the exponential function.